# ActiveMQCPP - Identifying Meesage type

Tags: c++, activemq-cpp

I've worked with activemqcpp API before in a few projects, but I've always known what type the message are beforehand, so the dynamic casting to the corresponding message subclass was safe.

Now I'm building a wrapper for the MQ library and can't find a way to recognize from a base Message pointer (as returned by a receive) what message subclass does it match to cast it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do things the pure C++ way then you can play around with using the typeid operator from C++ RTTI to inspect the object to see what it is.

A simpler way is to cast to the underlying message type that all CMS Message instances are derived from:

```
activemq::core::commands::Message
```

This class offers a method `getDataStructureType()` methods that returns the type via an assigned ID used in the OpenWire protocol:

```
    const unsigned char ID_ACTIVEMQBLOBMESSAGE = 29;
    const unsigned char ID_ACTIVEMQBYTESMESSAGE = 24;
    const unsigned char ID_ACTIVEMQMAPMESSAGE = 25;
    const unsigned char ID_ACTIVEMQMESSAGE = 23;
    const unsigned char ID_ACTIVEMQOBJECTMESSAGE = 26;
    const unsigned char ID_ACTIVEMQSTREAMMESSAGE = 27;
    const unsigned char ID_ACTIVEMQTEXTMESSAGE = 28;
```

Or you can just try a dynamic cast to each type until the result is non-null.

Comment: I was using the dynamic_cast approach, given the activemq-cpp documentation I didn't know a cast to activemq::core was doable since it doesn't appear in the hierarchy tree of cms::message.

Comment: This is very disappointing.  typeid or dynamic cast, being very heavy handed, are not the "pure C++ way".  Rather, they are basically a form of writing Java in C++. Tibco CMS's C API provides the tibems_GetBodyType() call, that returns an enum value.  Simple, clean, and lightweight.  Too bad we can't have that here.

Comment: If only the source was freely available for someone to modify to fit their needs.....

Comment: I've only just started looking at activemq-cpp. This was one of the first issues that came up while considering a port of application code based on Tibco EMS.  Hence the disappointment, as given how long activemq-cpp has been around, it seems that something otherwise this obviously useful was never meant to be in the "official" API.